# Setting network device priority with nmcli in Fedora

Tags: networking, fedora, nmcli

I am on Fedora v33 Server edition (no GUI) and I have setup 2 network connections.
One is Ethernet, which I use to connect my Macbook to the Linux machine, the other is the WLAN connection the machine uses to connect to the internet.

So now whenever I do

`nmcli con up eno1`

I lose access to the Internet (`ping www.google.com` does not return any packets)

When the ethernet is down everything works, but I cannot use ethernet obviously.

Something similar can happen on a Mac OS where I can simply "drag" a network to set the priority. How do I do the same using only the terminal on a unix system like Fedora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some research I ran into this great tool called `nmtui`

`sudo dnf install NetworkManager-tui`

And after installing the tool and running it with `sudo nmtui` I edited my ethernet connection and saw the option called
`Never use this network for default route` which translates to the option `never-default=true` inside the `[ipv4]` in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` config file.

After that I ran `sudo nmcli con down eno1 && sudo nmcli con up eno1`  and after running `nmcli` again I can see that the order of connections charged, where now my WLAN is first and my ethernet connection is second.